# PHP checkbox problem (row not getting deleted)

Tags: php

I made a simple HTML web page with a list of emplyees (only two atm).

```
    <form method="post" action = "del.php">
    <table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "lavoratori";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "SELECT nome, id FROM operai";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo"<tr>";
                    echo'<td><input type = "checkbox" name = checkbox[]" value = '.$row['id']."<td>".$row['nome']."</td>";
                    echo"</tr>";  

                }
                echo"</table>";
            }
            $conn->close();
        ?>
        <input type = "submit" name = "delete" id = "delete" value = "Delete Records">
    </form>
```

This is del.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "lavoratori";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $chkarr = $_POST['checkbox'];
    foreach($chkarr as $id){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM operai WHERE id = .$id.";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
    header("Location: /test_purpose/home.php");
}
$conn->close();
```

?>

Can you guys tell me what's going on? I'm new to PHP.
What i'm trying to do is to delete a specific a row from selecting with a checkbox. And it does not work, it redirects me back to the main page, without deleting anything obviously.

Comment: You are missing quotes in HTML: `name = checkbox[]"`

Comment: What does `$result` show?

Comment: what is in `$id` ?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM operai WHERE id = .$id.";
```

Replace with:

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM operai WHERE id = {$id}";
```

You also need to consider `SQL Injection`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1403785

Comment: Or even better: Something like a prepared statement. `$id` is custom input, so it can be used for SQL injections.

Comment: Yes, you're right @ Jb31. I was helping him to understand the error :-)
Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: No guys, it didn't work.. sorry for being late. I followed a tutorial but somehow it looks wrong.

Comment: Guys, i fixed the issue.

Comment: Very good! If you're ok, accept tue answer (click on "check" icon, under the answer)